# Performance issue in Edge when using ng-bind-html

Tags: angularjs, typescript, microsoft-edge

To bind html content to div I use ng-bind-html. When I try to bind larger HTML it takes 5-6 seconds. This works fine in chrome browser. I use $sce.trustAsHtml() to make the HTML trusted. Has anyone run into similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

When I use $sce.getTrustedHtml() this delay doesn't happen since the HTML is already sanitized and browser simply binds the HTML with out doing any sanity check. It seems to me that when we use $sce.trustAsHtml() edge browser is doing sanity check and it is very slow.